# How to feed while loop one slice at a time?

Tags: bash, while-loop, record, ifs

If I want to read a string and split it on a given delimiter, I can set `IFS` and store string slices in an array. Then I can do whatever I want with its items:

```
while IFS=_ read -r -a myarray; do
    printf "%s -\n" "${myarray[@]}"
done <<< "a_b"
```

This returns:

```
$ while IFS=_ read -r -a myarray; do echo "hello"; printf "%s -\n" "${myarray[@]}"; done <<< "a_b"
hello
a -
b -
```

However, I sometimes want to read just one of these fields per loop. So I wonder if there is a way to have this `while` loop be fed by a slice every time. That is, on the first iteration have `read` get just `a`, on the second one just `b` and so on.

I found a way changing the way we feed the loop: instead `<<< "a_b"` I use `tr` to split this up by replacing every `_` with a new line with `< <(tr "_" "\n" <<<"a_b")`:

```
$ while IFS=_ read -r -a myarray; do echo "hello"; printf "%s -\n" "${myarray[@]}"; done < <(tr "_" "\n" <<<"a_b")
hello
a -
hello
b -
```

However, I wonder: is there any other way for this? As we have `IFS` to change the field separators, does Bash have any other variable to set the "record separators" like `awk` for example has?

Comment: could you not just use a for loop

Comment: Also you can use the `-d` option for read to treat the delimiter as an _ instead of a newline. I think this has nothing to do with bash behaviour.

Comment: `read` builtin is very limited and no where close to `awk` which supports all kind of regular expressions for `FS`, `RS` and `FPAT` variables to split the input in many ways. I don't think one can even provide multiple delimiters in `-d` option of `read`